# show web page based on url without actual folders on server

Tags: php, .htaccess, web

I don't even really know how to ask this question or what this would be called or if it's even possible. I've tried searching but I guess I just can't word the question properly.

What I'm trying to do is have a URL, say `mydomain.com/blog/2012/12`, but without the folder structure on my server `public_html/blog/2012/12/index.php`

Well, `public_html/blog/index.php` exists, but for the rest, I would like when visitors go to the page `mydomain.com/blog/2012/12`, for the web site to load an `index.php` file from somewhere else on the server, and show blog archives for December 2012 without a `404` page coming up because that folder doesn't actually exist.

ie, I don't want to have to create folders for every year/month.

Is this possible? I'm sure it's possible, I just can't figure out how to search for this particular topic.

Comment: Hi, I think it's commonly referred to as `routing`.. Lots of frameworks have it built it (see http://laravel.com for example).. otherwise check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15392024/is-there-an-standalone-php-routing-library

Comment: As this is a relatively common question, the following reference was put together which should be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained/

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much, I was spinning my wheels here.